Prevent TalkBack from announcing AccessibilityWindowInfo title
I'm developing a page within my app that opens in a new WebView. When this page loads, TalkBack announces the title of the AccessibilityWindowInfo, which is the app name. This is redundant because users are already deep within the app. Is there a way to disable TalkBack from announcing the window title in this scenario?
Additionally, TalkBack reads the description of the previous page (also a WebView), but this information isn't present in the TalkBack node tree log. Could someone explain why this might be happening?
